# Select only 1 record that suit condition

Tags: sql-server

I need to select only 1 record as follows, I need all `userIDS` with `inforce=N` only.

On the below data, I have 2 record of 1 `userID` record with `inforce` `Y` and `N`. I dont want to display `userID` `1` because it has an `inforce=Y`.

Below is the data on the DB:

```
userID  Invest_name Inforce
1       inv         y
1       inv2        N
3       fnrl        N
4       plfn        N
4       pol         N
```

I have tried the code below.

```
select userID,inforce 
from [ThusoTestDelete]
where inforce ='N' 
group by userID,inforce 

userID  Inforce
3       N
4       N
```

Comment: `HAVING COUNT()` or `NOT EXISTS()`

Comment: In the `Where` clause add... `AND USERID not in  (select userID from [ThusoTestDelete]  where inforce ='Y')`

Comment: Your example, as you found out, won't work, because you are only going to consider the rows that have Inforce set to 'N', regardless of whether other records exist or not. 

One way to approach your problem would be to use a CTE or subquery in which you look for all userIDs with Inforce = 'Y', and then select from your table using a `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: I'm confused:   do you WANT to get both `UserID` 3 & 4, or do you only want to get back 1 record, like it says in the subject line and first sentence of the question??   Because 3 & 4 is two records, not one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT TTD.UserId,
       TTD.Inforce
FROM dbo.ThusoTestDelete TTD
WHERE TTD.Inforce = 'N'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.ThusoTestDelete
                  WHERE E.UserID = TTD.UserID
                    AND E.Inforce = 'Y');
```

Or, if you just want the ID's, you could use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM dbo.ThusoTestDelete
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(CASE InForce WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT T1.userID
,       T1.inforce 
FROM    [ThusoTestDelete] T1
WHERE   T1.inforce ='N' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT  NULL
                    FROM    [ThusoTestDelete] T2
                    WHERE   T1.inforce ='Y' 
                        AND T2.userID = T1.userID
                    )
```

Note: `GROUP BY` should only be used if you want to aggregate data, if you only want unique records, you should use `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for do that

first you will extract your data with where  on inforce = 'N' and some rows that have inforce = 'y' and not in your base data and  group by your final data

```
SELECT userID,inforce
      FROM ThusoTestDelete
      WHERE inforce ='N' AND 
      userID NOT IN (
                    SELECT  userID
                    FROM    [ThusoTestDelete] T1
                    WHERE   T1.inforce ='Y' )
GROUP BY userID,inforce
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy understandable CTE version:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #t;

CREATE TABLE #t (
    USERID      INT
   ,Invest_name VARCHAR(20)
   ,Inforce     VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT
    INTO #t (
        USERID
       ,Invest_name
       ,Inforce)
    VALUES (1,'inv',  'Y')
          ,(1,'inv2', 'N')
          ,(3,'fnrl', 'N')
          ,(4,'plfn', 'N')
          ,(4,'pol',  'N');

--Get all the inforce 'Y' users 
WITH CTE_Y_Users AS 
(
    SELECT
            DISTINCT USERID
        FROM #t
        WHERE Inforce = 'Y'
)
-- Get all the inforce 'N' users who are not in the 'Y' users list.
SELECT
        USERID
       ,Invest_name
       ,Inforce
    FROM #t
    WHERE Inforce = 'N' 
        AND USERID NOT IN (
            SELECT USERID
            FROM CTE_Y_Users
        )
```